# How to find diagonal value

Tags: javascript, matrix, foreach

I want to find the sum of the values of an array. The array maybe like this:

```
const maxtrix = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 10, 7, 5],
    [8, 11, 15, 9],
    [6, 19, 4, 14],
]
```

I want to find the value like this `[4, 7, 11, 6]` in an array.

I tried to do this but I couldn't organize the code.

Here is the code what I wrote:

```js
const maxtrix = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 10, 7, 5],
  [8, 11, 15, 9],
  [6, 19, 4, 14],
]

// right - 4, 7, 11, 6

let left = 0;
let rowLenth = maxtrix.length - 1;
let colLength = maxtrix[0].length - 1;

maxtrix.forEach((a, r) => {
  a.forEach((b, c) => {
    console.log(maxtrix[r][colLength - c])
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the right idea. Ditch the foreach on the columns because you only want one value per row.

Try this:

```js
const maxtrix = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 10, 7, 5],
    [8, 11, 15, 9],
    [6, 19, 4, 14],
]

let colLength = maxtrix[0].length - 1;
maxtrix.forEach((a, r) => {
    // In diagonal values c = r
    let c = r;
    // But we're doing reverse diagonal values
    c = colLength - c;
    console.log(maxtrix[r][c])
})
```

Same idea as you were doing, but we use `c = r` from the definition of diagonal entries.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to get `[4, 7, 11, 6]` in an array rather than just log the values to the console, [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the tool you want. `map()` provides an index value to the function that you can use to get the right value from each row:

```js
const matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 10, 7, 5],
    [8, 11, 15, 9],
    [6, 19, 4, 14],
]
let diagonal = matrix.map((row, index, self) => row[self.length - 1 - index])
console.log(diagonal)
```

You mentioned wanting the sum. You can do almost the same thing, but use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead to get them sum:

```js
const matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 10, 7, 5],
    [8, 11, 15, 9],
    [6, 19, 4, 14],
]
let sumOfDiagonals = matrix.reduce((sum, row, index, self) => sum + row[self.length - index - 1], 0)

console.log(sumOfDiagonals)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using a for loop, decrement by one starting from the last element in each row.

```js
var diagonal = (mat) => {
  let j = mat[0].length - 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < mat.length; i++, j--) {
    console.log(mat[i][j]);
  }
};

const maxtrix = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 10, 7, 5],
  [8, 11, 15, 9],
  [6, 19, 4, 14],
];
diagonal(maxtrix);
```